# error after clear basket

Tags: magento-2.1

I added a sample product to the basket. When I try to delete product from basket or clear basket an error is displayed.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Phrase, string given, called in /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php on line 121 and defined in /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php(121): Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException->__construct('Minimalne zam\xC3\xB3...') #1 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingProcessor.php(66): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement->assign('66', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address)) #2 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingAssignmentProcessor.php(110): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingProcessor->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Shipping), Object(Magento\Quote in /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php on line 51
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's magento internal issue so please open this file

> /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php

and check on  on line 121, check the code where exception is throwing.
There must be directly string passed in exception so just make it like:

> __("that exception here")

So simply means call this `__(" ")`  `there is two underscore in this function` and paste that string in this function. This should be place in same place where directly sting is passed.

For eg:
If this was like

> throw new \Exception("can not delete item");

So it should be like

> throw new \Exception(__("can not delete item"));

Save and check if it's working. If this works then please create new module and use preference to override this file.
It's not recommend to work directly on magento core file.

This function is used for translation which return `Magento\Framework\Phrase` object.

Answer (score 0):

I open file ShippingAddressManagement.php and here is code.

```
    $address->setSameAsBilling($sameAsBilling);
    $address->setSaveInAddressBook($saveInAddressBook);
    $address->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    if (!$quote->validateMinimumAmount($quote->getIsMultiShipping())) {
        throw new InputException($this->getMinimumAmountErrorMessage()->getMessage());
    }

    try {
        $address->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        throw new InputException(__('Unable to save address. Please check input data.'));
    }
    return $quote->getShippingAddress()->getId();
}
```

in line 121 is:

throw new InputException($this->getMinimumAmountErrorMessage()->getMessage());

it looks like it's all right but I dont know why get error.